# Functions not working well together

Tags: lengths, xstring

I'm developing a interface for setting and changing distance parameters for a package.  These distances are stored as strings so that the user can specify them in em and ex units if they want and they'll be expanded to the appropriate values at the time of use.  There's also a scaling algorithm which allows users to quickly scale all the distances up or down.  Now, while each of the functions has been tested and is working on its own, when I try to put them together I get errors that make no sense to me (LaTeX complains that \ifstretch is not defined when it clearly is just a handful of lines earlier).  Below is a MWE that extracts the relavent portion of the package.  As is, it raises no errors, but the rescaled distance isn't stored.  If I uncomment the line that is supposed to do that (line 100 of testing.sty) then the errors crop up (in the final implementation line 98, the testing line is also commented).  Can anyone tell me why these functions don't like working with each other and what I can do to fix that?

I apologize for the size of this MWE, but since the problem is related to the interaction of these functions, altering them to make them simpler might mask the problem.

Main document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{testing}

\def\test{1 cm
}

\newskip\testc
\testc = \test
\multiply\testc by 17
\divide\testc by 18

\begin{document}
\gresetdim{additionallineswidth}{\test}{1}

Original length:
\test

Stored length: \makeatletter
\gre@additionallineswidth

Manually Rescaled length:
\gre@convertto{cm}{\the\testc}

Internally Rescaled length:

Testing mode: \newfunction{additionallineswidth}{18}{17} %should be blank when properly implemented.

Implementation mode: \gre@additionallineswidth %should be the same as the manually rescaled length when properly implemented

\end{document}
```

testing.sty

```
% ------IDENTIFICATION------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{testing}
% For testing package code.

% ------INITIAL CODE------

% ------DECLARATION OF OPTIONS------

% ------EXECUTION OF OPTIONS------
\ProcessOptions

% ------PACKAGE LOADING------
\RequirePackage{xstring}

% ------MAIN CODE------

\AtBeginDocument{}

\AtEndDocument{}

\def\greerror#1{\PackageError{GregorioTeX}{#1}{}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Rescaling dimensions (for when \grefactor changes)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% This macro sets one dim (#1) to the value #2 and sets whether it should scale when the \grefactor changes (#3, 1 if yes, 0 if no).  While it does check that #1 can accept the kind of distance given in #2, it does not propagate the changes through the calculated distances.
\def\gresetdim#1#2#3{%
    \newif\ifchecklength\checklengthfalse
    \newif\ifbadlength\badlengthfalse
    %check if #2 is a rubber length (contains plus and/or minus)
    \IfSubStr{#2}{plus}{\checklengthtrue}{\relax}
    \IfSubStr{#2}{minus}{\checklengthtrue}{\relax}
    %if #1 is one of the distances which cannot be rubber.
    \ifchecklength
        \IfStrEq{#1}{additionallineswidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{maximumspacewithoutdash}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{additionalcustoslineswidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{minimalspaceatlinebeginning}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{manualinitialwidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{aboveinitialseparation}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{noclefspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovesignsspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{belowsignsspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{lowchoralsignsshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{highchoralsignsshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{translationheight}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextraise}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextheight}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{braceshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{curlybraceaccentusshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{clivisalignmentmin}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
    \fi
    % did both of the above conditions hold true?
    \ifbadlength
        \greerror{#1 cannot be a rubber length.}
    \else
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gre@scale@#1\endcsname{#3}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gre@#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \fi
    \relax %
}

%% an aux function adapting the value #1 from the factor #2 to the factor #3
%% Note: This function is assumed to touch only dimensions which are meant to scale with the \grefactor (i.e. if it acts on distance x, \gre@scale@x is 1)
\def\gre@changeonedimenfactor#1#2#3{%
    \newif\ifrubber\rubbertrue%
    % is length one that cannot be rubber?
    \IfStrEq{#1}{additionallineswidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{maximumspacewithoutdash}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{additionalcustoslineswidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{minimalspaceatlinebeginning}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{manualinitialwidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{aboveinitialseparation}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{noclefspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovesignsspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{belowsignsspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{lowchoralsignsshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{highchoralsignsshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{translationheight}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextraise}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextheight}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{braceshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{curlybraceaccentusshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{clivisalignmentmin}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \ifrubber% if we have a rubber allowed length we create a temporary skip
        \newskip\gre@temp%
    \else% otherwise we create a temporary dimen
        \newdimen\gre@temp%
    \fi%
    % Math
    \edef\gre@convert{\csname gre@#1\endcsname}%
    \gre@temp=\gre@convert%
    \multiply \gre@temp by \number #3%
    \divide \gre@temp by \number #2%
    % This testing line works
    \gre@consistentunits{\gre@convert}{\gre@temp}%
    % This implementation line doesn’t
%   \gresetdim{#1}{\gre@consistentunits{\gre@convert}{\gre@temp}}{1}
    \relax %
}


% These functions are used for stripping out the units and decimal portion of a distance to make it more amenable to being used in the conversion function below
{\catcode`p=12 \catcode`t=12 \gdef\gre@makein#1.#2pt{#1}}
{\catcode`p=12 \catcode`t=12 \gdef\gre@makenum#1pt{#1}}

% This function converts a distance to the units indicated in #1 and returns it as a string.
\def\gre@convertto#1#2{%
    \ifdim#2=0pt\relax%
        0 #1
    \else
        \newdimen\gre@unit%
        \expandafter\gre@unit = 1 #1%
        \newdimen\gre@base%
        \gre@base = #2%
        % Code to increase precision
        \newdimen\gre@maxlen%
        \gre@maxlen = 16383.99999pt%
        \newdimen\gre@factor%
        \gre@factor = \gre@maxlen%
        \divide\gre@factor by \gre@unit%
        \newdimen\gre@basefactor%
        \gre@basefactor = \gre@maxlen%
        \divide\gre@basefactor by \gre@base%
        \ifdim\gre@basefactor<\gre@factor%
            \advance\gre@basefactor by -10sp%
            \multiply\gre@unit by \gre@basefactor%
            \multiply\gre@base by \gre@basefactor%
        \else%
            \advance\gre@factor by -10sp%
            \multiply\gre@unit by \gre@factor%
            \multiply\gre@base by \gre@factor%
        \fi%
        \newcount\temp%
        \temp = \expandafter\gre@makein\the\gre@unit%
        \divide\gre@base by \temp%
        \expandafter\gre@makenum\the\gre@base\relax #1%
    \fi
}

% This function takes a distance (#2) and formats it as a string so that its units conform to the pattern set by a string representation of a distance (#1)
\def\gre@consistentunits#1#2{%
    \newif\ifstretch\stretchfalse%
    \newif\ifshrink\shrinkfalse%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{plus}{\stretchtrue}{\relax}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{minus}{\shrinktrue}{\relax}%
    \ifstretch%
        \ifshrink%
            %rubber with both stretch and shrink
            \StrBefore{#1}{plus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \StrBetween{#1}{plus}{minus}[\gre@stretchunit]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{minus}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
        \else%
            %rubber with stretch only
            \StrBefore{#1}{plus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{plus}[\gre@stretchunit]%
            \def\gre@shrinkunit{}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \ifshrink%
            %rubber with shrink only
            \StrBefore{#1}{minus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \def\gre@stretchunit{}%
            \StrBehind{#1}{minus}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
        \else%
            %non-rubber
            \def\gre@baseunit{#1}%
            \def\gre@stretchunit{}%
            \def\gre@shrinkunit{}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \StrDel{\gre@baseunit}{ }[\gre@baseunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@baseunit}{2}[\gre@baseunit]%
    \StrDel{\gre@stretchunit}{ }[\gre@stretchunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@stretchunit}{2}[\gre@stretchunit]%
    \StrDel{\gre@shrinkunit}{ }[\gre@shrinkunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@shrinkunit}{2}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
    \gre@convertto{\gre@baseunit}{\dimexpr#2\relax} %
    \IfStrEq{}{\gre@stretchunit}{}{%
        plus %
        \gre@convertto{\gre@stretchunit}{\gluestretch#2}
    }%
    \IfStrEq{}{\gre@shrinkunit}{}{%
        minus %
        \gre@convertto{\gre@shrinkunit}{\glueshrink#2}
    }%
}

\def\newfunction#1#2#3{%
    \gre@changeonedimenfactor{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While David's post diagnosed my problem, it didn't provide a fix.  Below is the version of testing.sty that I was able to make work based on David's answer.

*Edit:* After working with the code in situ, I discovered that I hadn't quite solved all my expansion issues.  While the first test printed nicely, extra non-printing stuff was getting placed in the stored string (which could be seen with a `\typeout`), resulting in problems with using it as a distance later in my code.  What I needed was a similar interface to `\convertto` where the result was stored in a macro using a `\edef` rather than handed out directly.  This change also required some changes to `\consistentunits` as it could no longer define its output macro in one go.  The code package below shows all my fixes and now works as desired.

```
% ------IDENTIFICATION------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]%
\ProvidesPackage{testing}%
% For testing package code.

% ------INITIAL CODE------

% ------DECLARATION OF OPTIONS------

% ------EXECUTION OF OPTIONS------
\ProcessOptions%

% ------PACKAGE LOADING------
\RequirePackage{xstring}%

% ------MAIN CODE------

\AtBeginDocument{}%

\AtEndDocument{}%

\def\greerror#1{\PackageError{GregorioTeX}{#1}{}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Rescaling dimensions (for when \grefactor changes)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% This macro sets one dim (#1) to the value #2 and sets whether it should scale when the \grefactor changes (#3, 1 if yes, 0 if no).  While it does check that #1 can accept the kind of distance given in #2, it does not propagate the changes through the calculated distances.
\newif\ifchecklength%
\newif\ifbadlength%
\def\gresetdim#1#2#3{%
    \checklengthfalse%
    \badlengthfalse%
    %check if #2 is a rubber length (contains plus and/or minus)
    \IfSubStr{#2}{plus}{\checklengthtrue}{\relax}%
    \IfSubStr{#2}{minus}{\checklengthtrue}{\relax}%
    %if #1 is one of the distances which cannot be rubber.
    \ifchecklength%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{additionallineswidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{maximumspacewithoutdash}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{additionalcustoslineswidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{minimalspaceatlinebeginning}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{manualinitialwidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{aboveinitialseparation}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{noclefspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovesignsspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{belowsignsspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{lowchoralsignsshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{highchoralsignsshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{translationheight}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextraise}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextheight}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{braceshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{curlybraceaccentusshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
        \IfStrEq{#1}{clivisalignmentmin}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}%
    \fi%
    % did both of the above conditions hold true?
    \ifbadlength%
        \greerror{#1 cannot be a rubber length.}%
    \else%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gre@scale@#1\endcsname{#3}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gre@#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \fi%
    \relax %
}%

%% an aux function adapting the value #1 from the factor #2 to the factor #3
%% Note: This function is assumed to touch only dimensions which are meant to scale with the \grefactor (i.e. if it acts on distance x, \gre@scale@x is 1)
\newif\ifrubber%
\newskip\gre@skip@temp%
\newdimen\gre@dimen@temp%
\def\gre@changeonedimenfactor#1#2#3{%
    \rubbertrue%
    % is length one that cannot be rubber?
    \IfStrEq{#1}{additionallineswidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{maximumspacewithoutdash}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{additionalcustoslineswidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{minimalspaceatlinebeginning}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{manualinitialwidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{aboveinitialseparation}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{noclefspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovesignsspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{belowsignsspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{lowchoralsignsshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{highchoralsignsshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{translationheight}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextraise}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextheight}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{braceshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{curlybraceaccentusshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{clivisalignmentmin}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \ifrubber% if we have a rubber allowed length we create a temporary skip
        \let\gre@temp\gre@skip@temp%
    \else% otherwise we create a temporary dimen
        \let\gre@temp\gre@dimen@temp%
    \fi%
    % Math
    \edef\gre@convert{\csname gre@#1\endcsname}%
    \gre@temp=\gre@convert%
    \multiply \gre@temp by \number #3%
    \divide \gre@temp by \number #2%
    \gre@consistentunits{\gre@convert}{\gre@temp}%
    \gresetdim{#1}{\gre@stringdist}{1}%
    \relax %
}%


% These functions are used for stripping out the units and decimal portion of a distance to make it more amenable to being used in the conversion function below
{\catcode`p=12 \catcode`t=12 \gdef\gre@makein#1.#2pt{#1}}%
{\catcode`p=12 \catcode`t=12 \gdef\gre@makenum#1pt{#1}}%

% This function converts a distance to the units indicated in #1 and returns it as a string.
\newdimen\gre@unit%
\newdimen\gre@base%
\newdimen\gre@maxlen%
\newcount\gre@unitfactor%
\newcount\gre@basefactor%
\newcount\temp%
\def\gre@convertto#1#2{%
    \ifdim#2=0pt\relax%
        \edef\gre@converted{0 #1}%
    \else%
        \expandafter\gre@unit = 1 #1%
        \gre@base = #2%
        % Code to increase precision
        \gre@maxlen = 16383.99999pt%
        \gre@unitfactor = \number\gre@maxlen%
        \divide\gre@unitfactor by \number\gre@unit%
        \gre@basefactor = \gre@maxlen%
        \divide\gre@basefactor by \gre@base%
        \ifnum\gre@basefactor<\gre@unitfactor%
%           \advance\gre@basefactor by -10sp%
            \multiply\gre@unit by \gre@basefactor%
            \multiply\gre@base by \gre@basefactor%
        \else%
%           \advance\gre@unitfactor by -10sp%
            \multiply\gre@unit by \gre@unitfactor%
            \multiply\gre@base by \gre@unitfactor%
        \fi%
        \temp = \expandafter\gre@makein\the\gre@unit%
        \divide\gre@base by \temp%
        \edef\gre@converted{%
            \expandafter\gre@makenum\the\gre@base #1%
        }%
    \fi%
}%

% This function takes a distance (#2) and formats it as a string so that its units conform to the pattern set by a string representation of a distance (#1)
\newif\ifstretch%
\newif\ifshrink%
\def\gre@consistentunits#1#2{%
    \stretchfalse%
    \shrinkfalse%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{plus}{\stretchtrue}{\relax}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{minus}{\shrinktrue}{\relax}%
    \ifstretch%
        \ifshrink%
            %rubber with both stretch and shrink
            \StrBefore{#1}{plus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \StrBetween{#1}{plus}{minus}[\gre@stretchunit]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{minus}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
        \else%
            %rubber with stretch only
            \StrBefore{#1}{plus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{plus}[\gre@stretchunit]%
            \def\gre@shrinkunit{\relax}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \ifshrink%
            %rubber with shrink only
            \StrBefore{#1}{minus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \def\gre@stretchunit{\relax}%
            \StrBehind{#1}{minus}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
        \else%
            %non-rubber
            \def\gre@baseunit{#1}%
            \def\gre@stretchunit{\relax}%
            \def\gre@shrinkunit{\relax}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \StrDel{\gre@baseunit}{ }[\gre@baseunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@baseunit}{2}[\gre@baseunit]%
    \StrDel{\gre@stretchunit}{ }[\gre@stretchunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@stretchunit}{2}[\gre@stretchunit]%
    \StrDel{\gre@shrinkunit}{ }[\gre@shrinkunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@shrinkunit}{2}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
    \gre@convertto{\gre@baseunit}{\dimexpr#2\relax}%
    \edef\gre@stringdist{\gre@converted}%
    \if\relax\gre@stretchunit\else%
        \gre@convertto{\gre@stretchunit}{\gluestretch#2}%
        \edef\gre@stringdist{\gre@stringdist plus \gre@converted}%
    \fi%
    \if\relax\gre@shrinkunit\else%
        \gre@convertto{\gre@shrinkunit}{\glueshrink#2}%
        \edef\gre@stringdist{\gre@stringdist minus \gre@converted}%
    \fi%
}%

\def\newfunction#1#2#3{%
    \gre@changeonedimenfactor{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
```

Comment: +1 glad you got it working, I wasn't clear enough in my head what the intention of some of the commands were to really change much so I stopped once I'd narrowed down the error:-)

Comment: Looks like I may have spoken too soon.  I'm coming across a problem that didn't show up in my initial testing after implementing the above fix.  @DavidCarlisle (or anyone) what's the protocol for this?  Do I ask another question once I've got the new problem narrowed down (I'm still working on that) or do I edit something in this one?

Comment: The "new problem" turned out to be another instance of the old problem that I hadn't caught the first time around.  See my edits above for how I solved it.

Comment: By the way I added a lot of apparently missing `%` in my version which are still missing here. I also used `\let` to alias `\gre@temp` rather than allocate a new one each time.

Comment: I eventually ran into those problems and have fixed them in situ, but never came back to edit my testing package.  I'll edit the above to make it completely working.

Answer (score 3):

Your macros do not work by expansion so they are not safe in an edef or as arguments to the string testing functions you are using. I made some minor cleanup moving `\new...` out of macros to the top level, and added a couple of `\show`

The log shows

```
> \z=macro:
->\test .
\gresetdim ...badlengthfalse \def \z {#2}\show \z 
                                                  \IfSubStr {#2}{plus}{\chec...
l.15 \gresetdim{additionallineswidth}{\test}{1}

? 
> \endz=undefined.
\gresetdim ...cklengthtrue }{\relax } \show \endz 
                                                  \IfSubStr {#2}{minus}{\che...
l.15 \gresetdim{additionallineswidth}{\test}{1}

? 
> \z=macro:
->\gre@consistentunits {\gre@convert }{\gre@temp }.
\gresetdim ...badlengthfalse \def \z {#2}\show \z 
                                                  \IfSubStr {#2}{plus}{\chec...
l.28 ...\newfunction{additionallineswidth}{18}{17}
                                                   %should be blank when pro...

? 
)
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 28.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ff566

?
```

showing the first call is OK but on the second call `#2` is

```
 \gre@consistentunits {\gre@convert }{\gre@temp }
```

which you can't use as an argument to `\IfSubStr`  so you never reach the following
line with

```
 \show\endz
```

---

Modified `testing.sty`

```
% ------IDENTIFICATION------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{testing}
% For testing package code.

% ------INITIAL CODE------

% ------DECLARATION OF OPTIONS------

% ------EXECUTION OF OPTIONS------
\ProcessOptions

% ------PACKAGE LOADING------
\RequirePackage{xstring}

% ------MAIN CODE------

\AtBeginDocument{}

\AtEndDocument{}

\def\greerror#1{\PackageError{GregorioTeX}{#1}{}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Rescaling dimensions (for when \grefactor changes)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% This macro sets one dim (#1) to the value #2 and sets whether it should scale when the \grefactor changes (#3, 1 if yes, 0 if no).  While it does check that #1 can accept the kind of distance given in #2, it does not propagate the changes through the calculated distances.
 \newif\ifchecklength
\newif\ifbadlength
\def\gresetdim#1#2#3{%
   \checklengthfalse
    \badlengthfalse
    %check if #2 is a rubber length (contains plus and/or minus)
\def\z{#2}\show\z
    \IfSubStr{#2}{plus}{\checklengthtrue}{\relax}
\show\endz
    \IfSubStr{#2}{minus}{\checklengthtrue}{\relax}
    %if #1 is one of the distances which cannot be rubber.
    \ifchecklength
        \IfStrEq{#1}{additionallineswidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{maximumspacewithoutdash}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{additionalcustoslineswidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{minimalspaceatlinebeginning}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{manualinitialwidth}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{aboveinitialseparation}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{noclefspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovesignsspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{belowsignsspace}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{lowchoralsignsshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{highchoralsignsshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{translationheight}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextraise}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextheight}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{braceshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{curlybraceaccentusshift}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
        \IfStrEq{#1}{clivisalignmentmin}{\badlengthtrue}{\relax}
    \fi
    % did both of the above conditions hold true?
    \ifbadlength
        \greerror{#1 cannot be a rubber length.}
    \else
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gre@scale@#1\endcsname{#3}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname gre@#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \fi
    \relax %
}

%% an aux function adapting the value #1 from the factor #2 to the factor #3
%% Note: This function is assumed to touch only dimensions which are meant to scale with the \grefactor (i.e. if it acts on distance x, \gre@scale@x is 1)
\newif\ifrubber
\def\gre@changeonedimenfactor#1#2#3{%
    \rubbertrue%
    % is length one that cannot be rubber?
    \IfStrEq{#1}{additionallineswidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{maximumspacewithoutdash}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{additionalcustoslineswidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{minimalspaceatlinebeginning}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{manualinitialwidth}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{aboveinitialseparation}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{noclefspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovesignsspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{belowsignsspace}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{lowchoralsignsshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{highchoralsignsshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{translationheight}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextraise}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{abovelinestextheight}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{braceshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{curlybraceaccentusshift}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{clivisalignmentmin}{\rubberfalse}{\relax}%
    \ifrubber% if we have a rubber allowed length we create a temporary skip
        \let\gre@temp\gre@temp@skip
    \else% otherwise we create a temporary dimen
        \let\gre@temp\gre@temp@dimen
    \fi%
    % Math
    \edef\gre@convert{\csname gre@#1\endcsname}%
    \gre@temp=\gre@convert%
    \multiply \gre@temp by \number #3%
    \divide \gre@temp by \number #2%
    % This testing line works
    \gre@consistentunits{\gre@convert}{\gre@temp}%
    % This implementation line doesn’t
   \gresetdim{#1}{\gre@consistentunits{\gre@convert}{\gre@temp}}{1}
    \relax %
}

\newskip\gre@temp@skip
\newdimen\gre@temp@dimen

% These functions are used for stripping out the units and decimal portion of a distance to make it more amenable to being used in the conversion function below
{\catcode`p=12 \catcode`t=12 \gdef\gre@makein#1.#2pt{#1}}
{\catcode`p=12 \catcode`t=12 \gdef\gre@makenum#1pt{#1}}

% This function converts a distance to the units indicated in #1 and returns it as a string.
\def\gre@convertto#1#2{%
    \ifdim#2=0pt\relax%
        0 #1
    \else
        \newdimen\gre@unit%
        \expandafter\gre@unit = 1 #1%
        \newdimen\gre@base%
        \gre@base = #2%
        % Code to increase precision
        \newdimen\gre@maxlen%
        \gre@maxlen = 16383.99999pt%
        \newdimen\gre@factor%
        \gre@factor = \gre@maxlen%
        \divide\gre@factor by \gre@unit%
        \newdimen\gre@basefactor%
        \gre@basefactor = \gre@maxlen%
        \divide\gre@basefactor by \gre@base%
        \ifdim\gre@basefactor<\gre@factor%
            \advance\gre@basefactor by -10sp%
            \multiply\gre@unit by \gre@basefactor%
            \multiply\gre@base by \gre@basefactor%
        \else%
            \advance\gre@factor by -10sp%
            \multiply\gre@unit by \gre@factor%
            \multiply\gre@base by \gre@factor%
        \fi%
        \newcount\temp%
        \temp = \expandafter\gre@makein\the\gre@unit%
        \divide\gre@base by \temp%
        \expandafter\gre@makenum\the\gre@base\relax #1%
    \fi
}

% This function takes a distance (#2) and formats it as a string so that its units conform to the pattern set by a string representation of a distance (#1)
\newif\ifstretch
\newif\ifshrink
\def\gre@consistentunits#1#2{%
    \stretchfalse%
   \shrinkfalse%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{plus}{\stretchtrue}{\relax}%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{minus}{\shrinktrue}{\relax}%
    \ifstretch%
        \ifshrink%
            %rubber with both stretch and shrink
            \StrBefore{#1}{plus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \StrBetween{#1}{plus}{minus}[\gre@stretchunit]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{minus}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
        \else%
            %rubber with stretch only
            \StrBefore{#1}{plus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{plus}[\gre@stretchunit]%
            \def\gre@shrinkunit{}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \ifshrink%
            %rubber with shrink only
            \StrBefore{#1}{minus}[\gre@baseunit]%
            \def\gre@stretchunit{}%
            \StrBehind{#1}{minus}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
        \else%
            %non-rubber
            \def\gre@baseunit{#1}%
            \def\gre@stretchunit{}%
            \def\gre@shrinkunit{}%
        \fi%
    \fi%
    \StrDel{\gre@baseunit}{ }[\gre@baseunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@baseunit}{2}[\gre@baseunit]%
    \StrDel{\gre@stretchunit}{ }[\gre@stretchunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@stretchunit}{2}[\gre@stretchunit]%
    \StrDel{\gre@shrinkunit}{ }[\gre@shrinkunit]%
    \StrRight{\gre@shrinkunit}{2}[\gre@shrinkunit]%
    \gre@convertto{\gre@baseunit}{\dimexpr#2\relax} %
    \IfStrEq{}{\gre@stretchunit}{}{%
        plus %
        \gre@convertto{\gre@stretchunit}{\gluestretch#2}%
    }%
    \IfStrEq{}{\gre@shrinkunit}{}{%
        minus %
        \gre@convertto{\gre@shrinkunit}{\glueshrink#2}%
    }%
}

\def\newfunction#1#2#3{%
    \gre@changeonedimenfactor{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for diagnosing the problem.  I thought I had taken care of the expansion issues with xstring, but didn't realize that the conditionals had similar problems.  See my answer post for how I was able to get things working.